# trying to understand getModifiers() in php

Tags: php

```
<?php
class Testing
{
    final public static function foo()
    {
        return;
    }
    public function bar()
    {
        return;
    }
}

$foo = new ReflectionMethod('Testing', 'foo');

echo "Modifiers for method foo():\n";
echo $foo->getModifiers() . "\n";
echo implode(' ', Reflection::getModifierNames($foo->getModifiers())) . "\n";

$bar = new ReflectionMethod('Testing', 'bar');

echo "Modifiers for method bar():\n";
echo $bar->getModifiers() . "\n";
echo implode(' ', Reflection::getModifierNames($bar->getModifiers()));
?>
```

Above code is taken from Example #1 `ReflectionMethod::getModifiers()` example in php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.getmodifiers.php

Question:
the code :`$foo->getModifiers()`, output is 261, what does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bitfield, consisting of the bitwise OR of [these constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php#reflectionmethod.constants.modifiers).

[`Reflection::getModifierNames`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflection.getmodifiernames.php) makes it a bit more understandable:

```
php> =Reflection::getModifierNames(261)
array(
  0 => "final",
  1 => "public",
  2 => "static",
)
```